# Controlling how much the document scroll on up/down arrow

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way in javascript by which we can control how much the document will scroll to (in terms of pixel) on pressing the up/down arrow of keyboard?

Comment: try google mate... first search result ::: http://plugins.learningjquery.com/smooth-scroll/

Comment: @jycr753 As i think tht's a seperate plugin. is thr any inbuilt javascript or jquery method

Comment: not that i cant think of my head, +1 since not i really want to know

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Just add an event handler to the keypress event, and then check if the key pressed is the up or down key, and if the focused element is the body via `document.activeElement`. It'd use a function like this:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    var n = 100;  //Enter the amount of px you want to scroll here
    if (e.which == 38 && document.activeElement == document.body) {
        e.preventDefault();
        document.body.scrollTop -= n;
    }
    if (e.which == 40 && document.activeElement == document.body) {
        e.preventDefault();
        document.body.scrollTop += n;
    }
});
```

That changes the amount of pixels scrolled to the amount entered at line 2 of that script. In this case, it'd be 100px.

Comment: but that will only work when scrolling with the keyboard, and now in days almost no one does that ... :S

Comment: To quote OP: "...on pressing the up/down arrow of keyboard". That was indeed exactly what OP asked for.